# sfdx force:source:deploy blocked on push

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

when pushing source via sfdx force:source:deploy - I get super random upload times. When running in debug mode, the command either runs smoothly or blocks at :

> sfdx:@salesforce/plugin-config:hooks:init start (require) C:\Program
> Files\sfdx\client\node_modules@salesforce\plugin-config\lib\hooks\init\load_config_meta.js

Any idea how I can unblock this step or accellerate deployment?

running `sfdx-cli/7.164.2 win32-x64 node-v16.17.0`

Thanks,